# Problemas com jQuery load | CORS

Tags: jquery, html

estou tentando "capturar" algumas informações contidas em uma página de terceiro diretamente em uma página que estou codando no momento.

Estou usando jquery para fazer isto, pois quero apenas uma ou duas informações que estão nesta página, no caso eu quero pegar apenas o preço e nome do produto que está no site da americanas.com e carregar diretamente no meu site. Para quando eles atualizarem la, no meu site atualiza automaticamente sem eu precisar ficar codando toda hora.

Estou tentando usando esta linha:

```
$( "#conteudo" ).load( "http://www.americanas.com/exemplo-produto #preco" );
```

Eu sou estudante ainda, mais pelo que sei até o momento o erro se da devido CORS, cross-origin resource sharing pois da o seguinte erro:

**Failed to load http://americanas.com/exemplo-produto: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' is therefore not allowed access.**

Pelo que eu sei até o momento eu não consigo resolver este problema, pois pelo que sei eu teria que pedir autorização para eles "me incluírem" na página que eu estou tentando requisitar?

Existe alguma outra opção para que eu consiga obter sucesso neste caso?

Muito obrigado!

Comment: CORS só se libera no servidor mesmo. Outra opção seria criar um crawler.

Comment: O usuário acima está correto, você poderia utilizar uma extensão do Chrome que "libera" isso ou então desativar as flags de verificação disso no Chrome. Porém, não resolve o seu problema para a produção, veja este link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256548/problema-com-cors-usando-ionic-e-lumen/261211#261211
O ideal seja que você faça um crawler, veja este exemplo: https://scrapy.org/
Aí então as informações são salvas no seu banco de dados e passadas ao usuário final.

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Eu vou fazer isto esta tarde, obrigado pelo seu tempo! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Isso acontece por que a página que você está tentando obter informações, possui um tipo de bloqueio para evitar esta ação de forma que não é possível acessá-la de um servidor externo.

Comment: Obrigado Fábio! Eu sei disso, mas como sou estudante ainda acabo apanhando de algumas coisas, mas muito obrigado pelo seu tempo! ;)